# nfs mounting problem VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS

Tags: linux, yocto, nfs, u-boot

I am not able to mount nfs, my Parameters are like following, it is from bootlin;

```
setenv bootargs 'console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/nfs rw
nfsroot=192.168.0.1:/nfs,nfsvers=3,tcp
ip=192.168.0.100:::::usb0 g_ether.dev_addr=f8:dc:7a:00:00:02
g_ether.host_addr=f8:dc:7a:00:00:01'

setenv bootcmd 'mmc dev 0; devnum=${mmcdev}; setenv devtype mmc;
mmc rescan; run loadimage; run findfdt; run mmcloados'
```

When I am on uboot console, I called ifconfig command on host, but I couldn't see the network interface. Is it normal?
How can I determine if the mac address is correct?

when I tried to ping, I get "host is not alive" feedback.

Bootlog looks like following;

```
U-Boot 2021.01-ga6e7892957 (May 14 2021 - 05:06:14 +0000)

CPU  : AM335X-GP rev 2.1
Model: TI AM335x BeagleBone Black
DRAM:  512 MiB
WDT:   Started with servicing (60s timeout)
NAND:  0 MiB
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
Loading Environment from FAT... OK
Net:   eth2: ethernet@4a100000, eth3: usb_ether
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
4944384 bytes read in 325 ms (14.5 MiB/s)
65774 bytes read in 13 ms (4.8 MiB/s)
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 88000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x88000000
   Loading Device Tree to 8ffec000, end 8ffff0ed ... OK

Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.10.30-gd85aee3e19 (oe-user@oe-host) (arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.34.0.20200220) #1 PREEMPT Fri May 7 18:33:44 UTC 2021
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [413fc082] revision 2 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: TI AM335x BeagleBone Black
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writeback
[    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 48 MiB at 0x9c800000
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000080000000-0x000000009fefffff]
[    0.000000]   HighMem  empty
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000080000000-0x000000009fefffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000080000000-0x000000009fefffff]
[    0.000000] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
[    0.000000] AM335X ES2.1 (sgx neon)
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 129666
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=192.168.0.1:/nfs,nfsvers=3,tcp ip=192.168.0.100:::::usb0 g_ether.dev_addr=f8:dc:7a:00:00:02 g_ether.host_addr=f8:dc:7a:00:00:01
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] Memory: 452372K/523264K available (10240K kernel code, 692K rwdata, 3336K rodata, 1024K init, 282K bss, 21740K reserved, 49152K cma-reserved, 0K highmem)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] rcu: Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU event tracing is enabled.
[    0.000000]  Trampoline variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 10 jiffies.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 16, nr_irqs: 16, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000000] IRQ: Found an INTC at 0x(ptrval) (revision 5.0) with 128 interrupts
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x324/0x4e0 with crng_init=0
[    0.000000] TI gptimer clocksource: always-on /ocp/interconnect@44c00000/segment@200000/target-module@31000
[    0.000009] sched_clock: 32 bits at 24MHz, resolution 41ns, wraps every 89478484971ns
[    0.000027] clocksource: dmtimer: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 79635851949 ns
[    0.000336] TI gptimer clockevent: 24000000 Hz at /ocp/interconnect@48000000/segment@0/target-module@40000
[    0.001256] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.001333] Calibrating delay loop... 996.14 BogoMIPS (lpj=4980736)
[    0.090406] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.090566] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    0.090581] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    0.091421] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.091494] CPU0: Spectre v2: using BPIALL workaround
[    0.092291] Setting up static identity map for 0x80100000 - 0x80100060
[    0.092430] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.092519] EFI services will not be available.
[    0.092875] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.102888] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant c rev 3
[    0.103133] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.103157] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes, linear)
[    0.106522] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.107450] DMI not present or invalid.
[    0.107895] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.110073] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.127754] l3-aon-clkctrl:0000:0: failed to disable
[    0.128925] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'fair_share'
[    0.128937] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'bang_bang'
[    0.128952] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    0.128959] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'user_space'
[    0.129305] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.129341] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    1.148982] No ATAGs?
[    1.149010] hw-breakpoint: debug architecture 0x4 unsupported.
[    1.172697] iommu: Default domain type: Translated 
[    1.174699] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    1.175150] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    1.175194] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    1.175300] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    1.175309] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    1.175332] PTP clock support registered
[    1.175391] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[    1.176597] Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.
[    1.177941] clocksource: Switched to clocksource dmtimer
[    1.185160] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    1.186139] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    1.186177] TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    1.186218] TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    1.186258] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
[    1.186373] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    1.186394] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    1.186536] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    1.187084] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    1.187101] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    1.187108] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    1.187114] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    1.187132] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    1.188552] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a8 PMU driver, 5 counters available
[    1.189793] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    1.190087] workingset: timestamp_bits=14 max_order=17 bucket_order=3
[    1.193778] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[    1.194528] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    1.194578] Key type id_resolver registered
[    1.194588] Key type id_legacy registered
[    1.194676] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[    1.194689] nfs4flexfilelayout_init: NFSv4 Flexfile Layout Driver Registering...
[    1.194734] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/O].
[    1.195340] Key type asymmetric registered
[    1.195357] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    1.195405] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 244)
[    1.195417] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    1.195426] io scheduler kyber registered
[    1.555186] omap-mailbox 480c8000.mailbox: omap mailbox rev 0x400
[    1.652454] debugfs: Directory '49000000.dma' with parent 'dmaengine' already present!
[    1.652500] edma 49000000.dma: TI EDMA DMA engine driver
[    1.672358] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: 142 pins, size 568
[    1.722033] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 10 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    1.726383] printk: console [ttyS0] disabled
[    1.726571] 44e09000.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x44e09000 (irq = 20, base_baud = 3000000) is a 8250
[    2.375855] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[    2.382982] omap_rng 48310000.rng: Random Number Generator ver. 20
[    2.389283] random: fast init done
[    2.392908] random: crng init done
[    2.414615] brd: module loaded
[    2.424526] loop: module loaded
[    2.432117] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    2.497968] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: davinci mdio revision 1.6, bus freq 1000000
[    2.505680] libphy: 4a101000.mdio: probed
[    2.512049] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: phy[0]: device 4a101000.mdio:00, driver SMSC LAN8710/LAN8720
[    2.521681] cpsw 4a100000.ethernet: initialized cpsw ale version 1.4
[    2.528155] cpsw 4a100000.ethernet: ALE Table size 1024
[    2.533505] cpsw 4a100000.ethernet: cpts: overflow check period 500 (jiffies)
[    2.540829] cpsw 4a100000.ethernet: Detected MACID = 6c:ec:eb:ab:52:64
[    2.549619] i2c /dev entries driver
[    2.555585] cpuidle: enable-method property 'ti,am3352' found operations
[    2.563165] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.569503] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    2.574856] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    2.582911] sdhci-omap 481d8000.mmc: supply vqmmc not found, using dummy regulator
[    2.591548] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    2.611739] davinci-mcasp 48038000.mcasp: IRQ common not found
[    2.629606] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.635179] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    2.644917] sit: IPv6, IPv4 and MPLS over IPv4 tunneling driver
[    2.652099] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.656950] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    2.661989] omap_voltage_late_init: Voltage driver support not added
[    2.669321] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    2.681322] mmc1: SDHCI controller on 481d8000.mmc [481d8000.mmc] using External DMA
[    2.695224] OMAP GPIO hardware version 0.1
[    2.728464] tps65217-pmic: Failed to locate of_node [id: -1]
[    2.740405] tps65217-bl: Failed to locate of_node [id: -1]
[    2.748809] tps65217 0-0024: TPS65217 ID 0xe version 1.2
[    2.755267] omap_i2c 44e0b000.i2c: bus 0 rev0.11 at 400 kHz
[    2.764284] omap_i2c 4819c000.i2c: bus 2 rev0.11 at 100 kHz
[    2.778397] omap_gpio 44e07000.gpio: Could not set line 6 debounce to 200000 microseconds (-22)
[    2.789190] sdhci-omap 48060000.mmc: Got CD GPIO
[    2.794188] sdhci-omap 48060000.mmc: supply vqmmc not found, using dummy regulator
[    2.879941] mmc0: SDHCI controller on 48060000.mmc [48060000.mmc] using External DMA
[    2.921947] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 1234
[    2.931057] tda998x 0-0070: found TDA19988
[    2.935744] mmcblk0: mmc0:1234 SA04G 3.68 GiB 
[    2.947658]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    2.951020] tilcdc 4830e000.lcdc: bound 0-0070 (ops tda998x_ops)
[    2.962961] [drm] Initialized tilcdc 1.0.0 20121205 for 4830e000.lcdc on minor 0
[    2.970854] tilcdc 4830e000.lcdc: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[    2.979434] tilcdc 4830e000.lcdc: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[    3.173535] mmc1: new high speed MMC card at address 0001
[    3.180862] mmcblk1: mmc1:0001 MMC04G 3.66 GiB 
[    3.186126] mmcblk1boot0: mmc1:0001 MMC04G partition 1 1.00 MiB
[    3.192926] mmcblk1boot1: mmc1:0001 MMC04G partition 2 1.00 MiB
[    3.199477] mmcblk1rpmb: mmc1:0001 MMC04G partition 3 128 KiB, chardev (243:0)
[    3.211617]  mmcblk1: p1
[   15.448539] ALSA device list:
[   15.451579]   No soundcards found.
[  111.209007] VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS.
[  111.213900] devtmpfs: mounted
[  111.221944] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1024K
[  111.240361] Run /sbin/init as init process
[  111.246257] Run /etc/init as init process
[  111.250600] Run /bin/init as init process
[  111.254784] Run /bin/sh as init process
[  111.259326] Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance.
[  111.273591] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance. ]---
```

environment variables are like above;

```
    =>   printenv
addr_fit=0x90000000
arch=arm
args_mmc=run finduuid;setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=PARTUUID=${uuid} rw rootfstype=${mmcrootfstype}
baudrate=115200
board=am335x
board_name=A335BNLT
board_rev=00C0
board_serial=5014BBBK1826
boot_a_script=load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${scriptaddr} ${prefix}${script}; source ${scriptaddr}
boot_efi_binary=load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${kernel_addr_r} efi/boot/bootarm.efi; if fdt addr ${fdt_addr_r}; then bootefi ${kernel_addr_r} ${fdt_addr_r};else bootefi ${kernel_addr_r} ${fdtcontroladdr};fi
boot_efi_bootmgr=if fdt addr ${fdt_addr_r}; then bootefi bootmgr ${fdt_addr_r};else bootefi bootmgr;fi
boot_extlinux=sysboot ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} any ${scriptaddr} ${prefix}${boot_syslinux_conf}
boot_fdt=try
boot_fit=0
boot_net_usb_start=usb start
boot_prefixes=/ /boot/
boot_script_dhcp=boot.scr.uimg
boot_scripts=boot.scr.uimg boot.scr
boot_syslinux_conf=extlinux/extlinux.conf
boot_targets=mmc0 legacy_mmc0 mmc1 legacy_mmc1 nand0 usb0 pxe dhcp 
bootargs=console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=192.168.0.1:/nfs,nfsvers=3,tcp ip=192.168.0.100:::::usb0 g_ether.dev_addr=f8:dc:7a:00:00:02 g_ether.host_addr=f8:dc:7a:00:00:01
bootcmd=mmc dev 0; devnum=${mmcdev}; setenv devtype mmc; mmc rescan; run loadimage; run findfdt; run mmcloados
bootcmd_dhcp=setenv devtype dhcp; run boot_net_usb_start; if dhcp ${scriptaddr} ${boot_script_dhcp}; then source ${scriptaddr}; fi;setenv efi_fdtfile ${fdtfile}; if test -z "${fdtfile}" -a -n "${soc}"; then setenv efi_fdtfile ${soc}-${board}${boardver}.dtb; fi; setenv efi_old_vci ${bootp_vci};setenv efi_old_arch ${bootp_arch};setenv bootp_vci PXEClient:Arch:00010:UNDI:003000;setenv bootp_arch 0xa;if dhcp ${kernel_addr_r}; then tftpboot ${fdt_addr_r} dtb/${efi_fdtfile};if fdt addr ${fdt_addr_r}; then bootefi ${kernel_addr_r} ${fdt_addr_r}; else bootefi ${kernel_addr_r} ${fdtcontroladdr};fi;fi;setenv bootp_vci ${efi_old_vci};setenv bootp_arch ${efi_old_arch};setenv efi_fdtfile;setenv efi_old_arch;setenv efi_old_vci;
bootcmd_legacy_mmc0=setenv mmcdev 0; setenv bootpart 0:2 ; run mmcboot
bootcmd_legacy_mmc1=setenv mmcdev 1; setenv bootpart 1:2 ; run mmcboot
bootcmd_mmc0=devnum=0; run mmc_boot
bootcmd_mmc1=devnum=1; run mmc_boot
bootcmd_nand=run nandboot
bootcmd_orig=if test ${boot_fit} -eq 1; then run update_to_fit; fi; run findfdt; run init_console; run envboot; run distro_bootcmd
bootcmd_pxe=run boot_net_usb_start; dhcp; if pxe get; then pxe boot; fi
bootcmd_usb0=devnum=0; run usb_boot
bootcount=1
bootdelay=2
bootdir=/boot
bootenvfile=uEnv.txt
bootfile=zImage
bootm_size=0x10000000
bootpart=0:2
bootscript=echo Running bootscript from mmc${mmcdev} ...; source ${loadaddr}
console=ttyO0,115200n8
cpu=armv7
dfu_alt_info_emmc=rawemmc raw 0 3751936;boot part 1 1;rootfs part 1 2;MLO fat 1 1;MLO.raw raw 0x100 0x200;u-boot.img.raw raw 0x300 0x1000;u-env.raw raw 0x1300 0x200;spl-os-args.raw raw 0x1500 0x200;spl-os-image.raw raw 0x1700 0x6900;spl-os-args fat 1 1;spl-os-image fat 1 1;u-boot.img fat 1 1;uEnv.txt fat 1 1
dfu_alt_info_mmc=boot part 0 1;rootfs part 0 2;MLO fat 0 1;MLO.raw raw 0x100 0x200;u-boot.img.raw raw 0x300 0x1000;u-env.raw raw 0x1300 0x200;spl-os-args.raw raw 0x1500 0x200;spl-os-image.raw raw 0x1700 0x6900;spl-os-args fat 0 1;spl-os-image fat 0 1;u-boot.img fat 0 1;uEnv.txt fat 0 1
dfu_alt_info_nand=SPL part 0 1;SPL.backup1 part 0 2;SPL.backup2 part 0 3;SPL.backup3 part 0 4;u-boot part 0 5;u-boot-spl-os part 0 6;kernel part 0 8;rootfs part 0 9
dfu_alt_info_ram=kernel ram 0x80200000 0x4000000;fdt ram 0x80f80000 0x80000;ramdisk ram 0x81000000 0x4000000
distro_bootcmd=for target in ${boot_targets}; do run bootcmd_${target}; done
dtboaddr=0x89000000
efi_dtb_prefixes=/ /dtb/ /dtb/current/
envboot=mmc dev ${mmcdev}; if mmc rescan; then echo SD/MMC found on device ${mmcdev};if run loadbootscript; then run bootscript;else if run loadbootenv; then echo Loaded env from ${bootenvfile};run importbootenv;fi;if test -n $uenvcmd; then echo Running uenvcmd ...;run uenvcmd;fi;fi;fi;
eth1addr=6c:ec:eb:ab:52:66
eth2addr=6c:ec:eb:ab:52:64
eth3addr=de:ad:be:ef:00:01
ethact=usb_ether
ethaddr=6c:ec:eb:ab:52:64
fdt_addr_r=0x88000000
fdtaddr=0x88000000
fdtcontroladdr=9df41050
fdtfile=undefined
findfdt=if test $board_name = A335BONE; then setenv fdtfile am335x-bone.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = A335BNLT; then setenv fdtfile am335x-boneblack.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = A335PBGL; then setenv fdtfile am335x-pocketbeagle.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = BBBW; then setenv fdtfile am335x-boneblack-wireless.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = BBG1; then setenv fdtfile am335x-bonegreen.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = BBGW; then setenv fdtfile am335x-bonegreen-wireless.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = BBBL; then setenv fdtfile am335x-boneblue.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = BBEN; then setenv fdtfile am335x-sancloud-bbe.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = A33515BB; then setenv fdtfile am335x-evm.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = A335X_SK; then setenv fdtfile am335x-evmsk.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = A335_ICE; then setenv fdtfile am335x-icev2.dtb; fi; if test $fdtfile = undefined; then echo WARNING: Could not determine device tree to use; fi; 
finduuid=part uuid mmc ${bootpart} uuid
get_overlaystring=for overlay in $name_overlays;do;setenv overlaystring ${overlaystring}'#'${overlay};done;
importbootenv=echo Importing environment from mmc${mmcdev} ...; env import -t ${loadaddr} ${filesize}
init_console=if test $board_name = A335_ICE; then setenv console ttyO3,115200n8;else setenv console ttyO0,115200n8;fi;
ipaddr=192.168.0.100
kernel_addr_r=0x82000000
load_efi_dtb=load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${fdt_addr_r} ${prefix}${efi_fdtfile}
loadaddr=0x82000000
loadbootenv=fatload mmc ${mmcdev} ${loadaddr} ${bootenvfile}
loadbootscript=load mmc ${mmcdev} ${loadaddr} boot.scr
loadfdt=load ${devtype} ${bootpart} ${fdtaddr} ${bootdir}/${fdtfile}
loadimage=load ${devtype} ${bootpart} ${loadaddr} ${bootdir}/${bootfile}
loadramdisk=load mmc ${mmcdev} ${rdaddr} ramdisk.gz
mmc_boot=if mmc dev ${devnum}; then devtype=mmc; run scan_dev_for_boot_part; fi
mmcboot=mmc dev ${mmcdev}; devnum=${mmcdev}; devtype=mmc; if mmc rescan; then echo SD/MMC found on device ${mmcdev};if run loadimage; then run args_mmc; if test ${boot_fit} -eq 1; then run run_fit; else run mmcloados;fi;fi;fi;
mmcdev=0
mmcloados=if test ${boot_fdt} = yes || test ${boot_fdt} = try; then if run loadfdt; then bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}; else if test ${boot_fdt} = try; then bootz; else echo WARN: Cannot load the DT; fi; fi; else bootz; fi;
mmcrootfstype=ext4 rootwait
mtdids=nand0=nand.0
mtdparts=mtdparts=nand.0:128k(NAND.SPL),128k(NAND.SPL.backup1),128k(NAND.SPL.backup2),128k(NAND.SPL.backup3),256k(NAND.u-boot-spl-os),1m(NAND.u-boot),128k(NAND.u-boot-env),128k(NAND.u-boot-env.backup1),8m(NAND.kernel),-(NAND.file-system)
name_fit=fitImage
nandargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=${nandroot} rootfstype=${nandrootfstype}
nandboot=echo Booting from nand ...; run nandargs; nand read ${fdtaddr} NAND.u-boot-spl-os; nand read ${loadaddr} NAND.kernel; bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}
nandroot=ubi0:rootfs rw ubi.mtd=NAND.file-system,2048
nandrootfstype=ubifs rootwait=1
netargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=${serverip}:${rootpath},${nfsopts} rw ip=dhcp
netboot=echo Booting from network ...; setenv autoload no; dhcp; run netloadimage; run netloadfdt; run netargs; bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}
netloadfdt=tftp ${fdtaddr} ${fdtfile}
netloadimage=tftp ${loadaddr} ${bootfile}
nfsopts=nolock
partitions=uuid_disk=${uuid_gpt_disk};name=bootloader,start=384K,size=1792K,uuid=${uuid_gpt_bootloader};name=rootfs,start=2688K,size=-,uuid=${uuid_gpt_rootfs}
pxefile_addr_r=0x80100000
ramargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=${ramroot} rootfstype=${ramrootfstype}
ramboot=echo Booting from ramdisk ...; run ramargs; bootz ${loadaddr} ${rdaddr} ${fdtaddr}
ramdisk_addr_r=0x88080000
ramroot=/dev/ram0 rw
ramrootfstype=ext2
rdaddr=0x88080000
rootpath=/export/rootfs
run_fit=bootm ${addr_fit}#${fdtfile}${overlaystring}
scan_dev_for_boot=echo Scanning ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart}...; for prefix in ${boot_prefixes}; do run scan_dev_for_extlinux; run scan_dev_for_scripts; done;run scan_dev_for_efi;
scan_dev_for_boot_part=part list ${devtype} ${devnum} -bootable devplist; env exists devplist || setenv devplist 1; for distro_bootpart in ${devplist}; do if fstype ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} bootfstype; then run scan_dev_for_boot; fi; done; setenv devplist
scan_dev_for_efi=setenv efi_fdtfile ${fdtfile}; if test -z "${fdtfile}" -a -n "${soc}"; then setenv efi_fdtfile ${soc}-${board}${boardver}.dtb; fi; for prefix in ${efi_dtb_prefixes}; do if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${prefix}${efi_fdtfile}; then run load_efi_dtb; fi;done;run boot_efi_bootmgr;if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} efi/boot/bootarm.efi; then echo Found EFI removable media binary efi/boot/bootarm.efi; run boot_efi_binary; echo EFI LOAD FAILED: continuing...; fi; setenv efi_fdtfile
scan_dev_for_extlinux=if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${prefix}${boot_syslinux_conf}; then echo Found ${prefix}${boot_syslinux_conf}; run boot_extlinux; echo SCRIPT FAILED: continuing...; fi
scan_dev_for_scripts=for script in ${boot_scripts}; do if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${prefix}${script}; then echo Found U-Boot script ${prefix}${script}; run boot_a_script; echo SCRIPT FAILED: continuing...; fi; done
scriptaddr=0x80000000
serial#=5014BBBK1826
serverip=192.168.0.1
soc=am33xx
spiargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=${spiroot} rootfstype=${spirootfstype}
spiboot=echo Booting from spi ...; run spiargs; sf probe ${spibusno}:0; sf read ${loadaddr} ${spisrcaddr} ${spiimgsize}; bootz ${loadaddr}
spibusno=0
spiimgsize=0x362000
spiroot=/dev/mtdblock4 rw
spirootfstype=jffs2
spisrcaddr=0xe0000
static_ip=${ipaddr}:${serverip}:${gatewayip}:${netmask}:${hostname}::off
stderr=serial@44e09000
stdin=serial@44e09000
stdout=serial@44e09000
update_to_fit=setenv loadaddr ${addr_fit}; setenv bootfile ${name_fit}
usb_boot=usb start; if usb dev ${devnum}; then devtype=usb; run scan_dev_for_boot_part; fi
usbnet_devaddr=f8:dc:7a:00:00:02
usbnet_hostaddr=f8:dc:7a:00:00:01
vendor=ti
ver=U-Boot 2021.01-ga6e7892957 (May 14 2021 - 05:06:14 +0000)

Environment size: 10427/131068 bytes
=>
```

I created a cfg file and added it to my kernel recipe, configuration is below. But I am still unable to achieve nfs mounting. Any suggestions?
Is there a way to make sure, may configuration changes are in the built kernel?

I have put all files, MLO, Uboot, dtb and zImage in Boot partition of the sdcard, is it correct?

```
  CONFIG_USB_COMMON=y
    CONFIG_USB_MUSB_HDRC=y
    CONFIG_USB_MUSB_GADGET=y
    CONFIG_USB_MUSB_DSPS=y
    CONFIG_NOP_USB_XCEIV=y
    CONFIG_AM335X_CONTROL_USB=y
    CONFIG_AM335X_PHY_USB=y
    CONFIG_USB_GADGET=y
    CONFIG_USB_LIBCOMPOSITE=y
    CONFIG_USB_U_ETHER=y
    CONFIG_USB_F_ECM=y
    CONFIG_USB_F_SUBSET=y
    CONFIG_USB_F_RNDIS=y
    CONFIG_USB_ETH=y
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to show more of the boot log, especially messages regarding protocols and networking.  Did you try to `ping` the NFS server from the U-Boot command line?  Also a `printenv` of your U-Boot environment might be informative.

Comment: thank you for your answer sawdust, I have edited the entry added the information you asked.

Comment: Seems like you have multiple issues on both ends.  The ping indicates that the NFS server is not available.  The client's boot log indicates that the Ethernet interface is not up to even try a connection.  The `ip=` command parameter has `usb0` as the `<device>`, but I suspect that is not a valid name for an Ethernet device/interface (since USB is a bus rather than a device).  The kernel command line has some parameters for a USB Ethernet gadget.  Are you trying to use that gadget as the Ethernet connection???

Comment: yes, I try to use usb-ethernet cable, beaglebone black support that. I didn't connect ethernet cable, should I?

I checked on the host with command "ps ef | grep nfs" nfs seems working. There wasn't much settings to do on hose side for nfs.

I have noticed that uboot env parameter ethaddr and eth2addr has same values.
How can I know if my mac address is correct?
Thank you again

Comment: Your kernel boot indicates no USB initialization at all.  Are all the USB drivers built in the kernel image or built as loadable modules?

Comment: Hi Sawdust, 
after I changed the following parameters;
 setenv ethact usb_ether
setenv usbnet_devaddr f8:dc:7a:00:00:02
setenv usbnet_hostaddr f8:dc:7a:00:00:01
setenv ipaddr 192.168.0.100
setenv serverip 192.168.0.1

I could ping the host from uboot, but nfs mounting is still not successful. I will check USB drivers of kernel too. thank you. 

I have updated the envVar and Boot log output.

Comment: Hi Sawdust,

by using nfs command on u-boot console, I could transfer single file to ram. but when I give the path of rfs, it does not mount. Would this information help you to give me suggestions? 
file I transferred was not a folder, it was zImage. It seems like, it does not transfer the folders.

Comment: The "ping from U-Boot" was simply a sanity check.  Plus I did not fully grasp your plan back then.  For now, you have to focus on building the kernel with all of the necessary USB drivers as part of the image.  The default config of USB drivers built as loadable modules cannot work in your planned usage.  That creates a chicken versus egg issue.

Comment: Or maybe you need to take several intermediate steps.  Try booting with the rootfs on the SD card.  Once the system is up, test the usb0 interface as an ethernet gadget.  If the host has a TFTP server, you could test some transfers.  Then test a NFS connection.  Then  try booting with the rootfs using the usb0 interface.

Comment: Hi Sawdust, 
I had booted with sdcard, it works fine. 

I checked the .config file on the following folder;
tmp/work/bootlinlabs-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-ti-staging/5.10.30+gitAUTOINC+d85aee3e19-a/build 

changes I made was not inside, am I looking wrong folder or is my bbappend file is wrong;

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI += "file://defconfig"

Comment: "*it works fine*" -- What is "*it*"?  I mentioned four steps to perform.  Did you actually do all four?  If you had, then why didn't you mention this before?  But if you merely booted from SD card, then that is not success and you have a lot more to do.   Sorry, I don't use Yocto, and can provide no advice on how to use Yocto.

Comment: okey, thank you, I had updated my entry, after I made additional steps. I didn't do all in the begining.

Comment: I could make the nfs mounting and tftp booting, after I configured the kernel. Thank you.