# How to change U boot console from UART0 to UART5 in beagle bone blue

Tags: u-boot

I am currently working on configuring U-Boot on the Beagle Bone Blue, specifically aiming to change the U-Boot console from UART0 to UART5. I have adjusted the console setting in the /boot/uEnv.txt file to console = ttyS5,115200n8.

However, I'm encountering an issue where during the boot process, half of the messages are still being directed to UART0, and the remaining messages are appearing on UART5. My goal is to have all the booting messages consolidated and displayed exclusively on UART5.

I have reviewed the U-Boot environment variables, and they seem to be correctly set for UART5. I have also considered checking device tree overlays and bootloader configurations, but the issue persists.

If you have any insights or suggestions on how to ensure that all booting messages are directed to UART5, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Additionally, if there are specific configurations or settings that I may have overlooked, please feel free to point them out.

Thank you for your time and assistance. I look forward to hearing from you.

Mohan

Comment: You seem confused. Your title mentions *"U boot [sic] console*". But the only tag you assigned to your post is just `linux-kernel` (which I have edited/replaced). You provide ambiguous descriptions of "*half of the messages*" versus "*the remaining messages*". You seem to focus solely  on what affects the kernel, i.e.  U-boot's environment variables, and ignore the actual configuration of U-Boot itself. Which version of U-Boot are you building/using? Does this U-Boot use its own Device Tree?

Comment: "*I have reviewed the U-Boot environment variables, and they seem to be correctly set for UART5.*" -- Then (contradict yourself and) post the actual U-Boot environment, i.e. the output from the `printenv` command.

Comment: the printenv will gSHELL=/bin/bash
SUDO_GID=1000
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/su
SUDO_USER=debian
PWD=/boot
LOGNAME=root
HOME=/root
LANG=en_IN
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:

Comment: cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.l

Comment: z4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb

Comment: =01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;

Comment: 31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35

Comment: :*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.w

Comment: ebm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;

Comment: 35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.c

Comment: gm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
TERM=xterm-256color
USER=root
SHLVL=1

Comment: NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
SUDO_UID=1000
MAIL=/var/mail/root
_=/usr/bin/printenv
OLDPWD=/home/debian

Comment: That's not a U-Boot environment; it's probably from your PC host. A U-Boot environment would look like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176624/nfs-mounting-problem-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-via-nfs BTW you've been a member for over a year; learn how to edit your post instead of using comments to present salient information.